# Why is .NET 6 Session using StackExchangeRedis creating so many connections?

Tags: asp.net, .net, redis, .net-6.0, stackexchange.redis

We have a .Net 6 MVC app using the built in UseSession storing the sessions in distributed cache(Redis) using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis package.

We have noticed that the redis server is taking an enormous amount of connections recieved compared to the number of requests recieved.

Setup DIstributed cache in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
        {
          options.Configuration = configuration["RedisCache:ConnectionString"];
        });
```

Setup Session in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
      {
        options.Cookie.Name = configuration.GetValue<string>("Session:CookieName");
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(configuration.GetValue<int>("Session:SessionTimeout"));
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
      });
```

Config in Configure:

```
 app.UseSession();
```

Any idea whats happening? The Connected Clients stays stable at 5, but the connections recieved is not proportionate to the amount of keys/users on the site.

The Redis is a Azure Cache For Redis with a C1-instance.

Redis

[image: Redis]

Comment: I assume a client can keep connecting, disconnecting and reconnecting? How long has your cache service been running?

Comment: 215.42h Uptime right now, same with web servers

Comment: A million connections in 9 days doesn't seem unreasonable to me, but I don't know what kind of load you are getting.

Comment: We have a legacy .net framework 4.8 running same packages and setup on a separate redis, which only creates 25119 connections recieved, but has 10x the amount of traffic. Seems this is somehow related to .net 6